# Solve using L'Hôpital rule

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Solve using L'Hôpital rule $\lim_{x\to 1} (1-x)^{\cos[(\Pi/2) x)]}$

So (...)

$$L=\lim_{x\to 1} (1-x)^{\cos[(\Pi/2) x)]} \rightarrow0^0$$
$$\ln L = \lim_{x\to 1} \ln (1-x)^{\cos[(\Pi/2) x)]}$$
$$\ln L = \lim_{x\to 1}\cos[(\Pi/2)] \ln(1-x)$$
$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to 1} \cfrac{\ln(1-x)}{\cfrac{1}{\cos[(\Pi/2)x]}}={\infty\over\infty} \rightarrow \text{Using L'Hôpital rule}$$
$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to 1} 
{ \cfrac{ \left({-1\over{1-x}}\right) } { \cfrac {-[{\Pi\over2}\cos x.-\sin x({\Pi\over2}x)] } {[\cos x({\Pi\over2}x)]^2} } } = \cfrac{\infty}{\infty} \rightarrow \text{Using L'Hôpital rule}$$
$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to 1} { \cfrac { 1 } { \cfrac { -[{\Pi\over2}(-\sin x)(-\sin x({\Pi\over2}x))-({\Pi\over2}(- \cos({\Pi\over2}x)))] } { [\cos({\Pi\over2}x)]^4 } } } $$

$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to 1} { \cfrac { [\cos({\Pi\over2}x)]^4 } { -[{\Pi\over2}(-\sin x)(- \sin({\Pi\over2}x))-({\Pi\over2}(- \cos({\Pi\over2}x)))] } } = 0$$

$$\ln L = 0 \rightarrow e^{\ln L} = e^0\rightarrow L = 1$$

I have an exam in two days, and I need to know: is this well done? If not, could someone point out the error to me?

Comment: Hmmm....¿Qué pasó con el término $\;-\frac1{1-x}\;$ después del primer l´Hospital? What happened with $\;\frac1{1-x}\;$ after the first application of l'Hospital?

Comment: $(-{1\over{1-x}})' = 1$

Comment: $(-1/(1-x))' = -((1-x)^{-1})' = (1-x)^{-2}(1-x)' = (1-x)^{-2}(-1) = -1/(1-x)^2$.

Comment: Oh, not at all! $$\left(-\frac1{1-x}\right)'=-\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: Did you mean $\pi$ instead of $\Pi$?

Answer (score 2):

An idea:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\log(1-x)}{\frac1{\cos\frac\pi2x}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{-\cos^2\frac\pi2x}{(1-x)\frac\pi2\sin\frac\pi2x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\frac\pi2\sin\pi x}{-\frac\pi2\sin\frac\pi2x+(1-x)\frac{\pi^2}4\cos\frac\pi2x}=\frac0{-\frac\pi2+0}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

If you keep differentiating $1/(1-x)$ it will get more and more singular! Don't do that! You could instead move the $1-x$ to the denominator for example. Also you seem to have two $x$ terms in the trigonometric functions which is wrong.

Alternatively let $u=1-x$, and use $\cos$ and $\sin$ relationships to get something of the form $\lim _{u\to 0} k u\ln u + \cdots$ which is zero.